Can I call TikTok's login API when my app is in Staging?
I'd developing a TikTok app and I'm receiving the following error when I try to reach the TikTok authorization page:
We couldn't log in with TikTok. This may be due to specific app settings.
If you're a developer, correct the following and try again:
client_key

I've confirmed that the client_key is correct, so I'm guessing it's a permissions issue.  My app is in Staging, does that prevent the client_key from working?
My caveman test consists of navigating to the URL:
https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=[client_key]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&scope=user.info.basic&response_type=code&state=afY73g
I've confirmed that:

The syntax above is correct.  Tested that by using a client_key for a fully functional app.
My redirect uri is correctly configured in the TikTok app configuration
The app has user.basic.info permissions.  However, as shown in the screenshot, not sure if that needs to be approved.
App Scopes
I confirmed my client_key is correct by making a successful call to the Client Access Token service.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm in the exact same situation and facing the same problem. I've scoured the Internet and this is the only place I even see the problem stated.

@TheodoreR.Smith  I actually did end up solving this.  I wrote to their support, and it turns out I had to fill out an Integration Assessment for Unreleased App form.  This is different from the standard app review process.  It grants some middle ground of rights, which was sufficient for me to at least get the login and basic API calls working.  The turnaround was pretty quick-- once I submitted, the screen said to wait 2-4 weeks for a response, but I got approved in about three days.

@GabeMerton I have the identical issue. I also suspect is because of my staging app. I will now fill out the Integration assessment form for unreleased app and hope it will work.

Jesus Christ - how dumb they have to be to not allow us to complete authentication flow in debug versions...
